# Why I can't use the FirebaseAuth.getInstance.deleteUser(uid);

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(uid);
System.out.println("Successfully deleted user.");
```

In this code，`deleteUser(uid)` shows that "Cannot resolve method 'deleteUser' in 'FirebaseAuth'". I don't know why. My doubt is that: there may be some conflicts between client SDK and service SDK. I have not created my service code and just want to test the function so I write all the code in the client.

I have tried a lot of ways, I want to know what should I do. Thank you guys.
If I need to separate the client and service then will it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a java program to delete users in Firebase Auth, you must use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).  You can't use the Android client SDK - it won't work at all outside of an Android app, and it doesn't even expose a method to delete a user by UID.  I suggest referring to the Firebase Admin documentation on [deleting a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Comment: Thank u for your reply. So if I want to use Firebase Admin SDK, I should have a new project without any Android client SDK right?

Comment: I don't know what IDE or programming environment you're using, but yes, you will have to write something that is not an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

While @DougStevenson solution solves the problem using the Firebase Admin SDK, please also note that the [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) class doesn't contain any `deleteUser(uid)` method. However, there is a [delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#delete()) method inside the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) class, which:

> Deletes the user record from your Firebase project's database.

So if you want to delete a user from an Android app, that's the function that you have to use.

One more thing to notice, the delete operation is an asynchronous operation, so you have to attach a listener to see when the operation is complete or fails with an error.

Comment: I got it. Firstly sign in a account and then delete which may be the best solution currently. Thank u :)

Comment: You're very welcome, Shiyu. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?